# How to send http data with header and body ia curl

Tags: curl, http-headers, netcat

I have captured following data using netcat

```
root@gitlab_new:/curl_hacks# nc -lp 5555
POST /project/PROJECT_ID HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
Authorization: Basic VVNFUl9JRDpUT0tFTl9JRA==
Connection: close
Host: localhost:5555
Content-Length: 1968

{"object_kind":"push","event_name":"push","before":"87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff","after":"84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c","ref":"refs/heads/master","checkout_sha":"84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c","message":null,"user_id":1,"user_name":"Administrator","user_username":"root","user_email":"admin@example.com","user_avatar":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80\u0026d=identicon","project_id":1,"project":{"id":1,"name":"hello-world","description":"","web_url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world","avatar_url":null,"git_ssh_url":"git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git","git_http_url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git","namespace":"root","visibility_level":0,"path_with_namespace":"root/hello-world","default_branch":"master","ci_config_path":null,"homepage":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world","url":"git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git","ssh_url":"git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git","http_url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git"},"commits":[{"id":"84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c","message":" M commit_history\n","timestamp":"2018-07-16T16:03:39+02:00","url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world/commit/84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c","author":{"name":"wakatana","email":"wakatana@topsecretmail.gov"},"added":[],"modified":["commit_history"],"removed":[]},{"id":"87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff","message":"1 commit\n","timestamp":"2018-07-16T12:55:13+02:00","url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world/commit/87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff","author":{"name":"wakatana","email":"wakatana@topsecretmail.gov"},"added":["commit_history"],"modified":[],"removed":[]}],"total_commits_count":2,"repository":{"name":"hello-world","url":"git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git","description":"","homepage":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world","git_http_url":"http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git","git_ssh_url":"git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git","visibility_level":0}}root@gitlab_new:/curl_hacks#
```

Those data were send via GitLab. Here they are shown in (more pretty) form as I can see it via GitLab web interface:

Request URL:

```
POST http://USER_ID:TOKEN_ID@localhost:5555/project/PROJECT_ID
```

Request headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
```

Request body:

```
{
  "object_kind": "push",
  "event_name": "push",
  "before": "87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff",
  "after": "84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c",
  "ref": "refs/heads/master",
  "checkout_sha": "84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c",
  "message": null,
  "user_id": 1,
  "user_name": "Administrator",
  "user_username": "root",
  "user_email": "admin@example.com",
  "user_avatar": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e64c7d89f26bd1972efa854d13d7dd61?s=80&d=identicon",
  "project_id": 1,
  "project": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "hello-world",
    "description": "",
    "web_url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world",
    "avatar_url": null,
    "git_ssh_url": "git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git",
    "git_http_url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git",
    "namespace": "root",
    "visibility_level": 0,
    "path_with_namespace": "root/hello-world",
    "default_branch": "master",
    "ci_config_path": null,
    "homepage": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world",
    "url": "git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git",
    "ssh_url": "git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git",
    "http_url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git"
  },
  "commits": [
    {
      "id": "84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c",
      "message": " M commit_history\n",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-16T16:03:39+02:00",
      "url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world/commit/84f95fb521fe48b357b6556f755b177fc9793d6c",
      "author": {
        "name": "wakatana",
        "email": "wakatana@topsecretmail.gov"
      },
      "added": [

      ],
      "modified": [
        "commit_history"
      ],
      "removed": [

      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff",
      "message": "1 commit\n",
      "timestamp": "2018-07-16T12:55:13+02:00",
      "url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world/commit/87257922812b7ce1e84f2ff4a74f9548e7b521ff",
      "author": {
        "name": "wakatana",
        "email": "wakatana@topsecretmail.gov"
      },
      "added": [
        "commit_history"
      ],
      "modified": [

      ],
      "removed": [

      ]
    }
  ],
  "total_commits_count": 2,
  "repository": {
    "name": "hello-world",
    "url": "git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git",
    "description": "",
    "homepage": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world",
    "git_http_url": "http://gitlab_new/root/hello-world.git",
    "git_ssh_url": "git@gitlab_new:root/hello-world.git",
    "visibility_level": 0
  }
}
```

How can I re-send those data but using curl? I've tried following (header.json and body.json are copied from GitLab web interface):

```
root@lubuntu18-64:~/curl_hacks# curl --head @header.json --data @body.json http://USER_ID:TOKEN_ID@localhost:5555/project/PROJECT_ID
Warning: You can only select one HTTP request method! You asked for both POST
Warning: (-d, --data) and HEAD (-I, --head).
```

As far as I understand the problem is that --head and --data cannot be used together but according to GitLab output I need to use both of them because something is header and something is data. What I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the HTTP headers `Content-Type: application/json` & `X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook`. You can specify additional HTTP header using [`-H` or `--header`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) :

```bash
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -H 'X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook' \
     -d @body.json "http://USER_ID:TOKEN_ID@localhost:5555/project/PROJECT_ID"
```

In your case, you have used [`--head` which is equivalent to `-I`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-I), it sends a `HEAD` request (eg it requests only the response headers)

Starting from curl 7.55.0, you can specify a file for the HTTP headers with header entry on each lines (but not json) :

```bash
curl -H @headers.txt -d @body.json "http://USER_ID:TOKEN_ID@localhost:5555/project/PROJECT_ID"
```

with headers.txt :

```
Content-Type: application/json
X-Gitlab-Event: Push Hook
```